# Express receiving empty req.body

Tags: node.js, express, fetch

When I call a fetch post request:

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/insertUser', {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: "no-cors",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ a: 1 })
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
        }).then(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
```

and receive it on the server with:

```
const path = require("path")
const express = require("express")
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express()

require('dotenv').config();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/insertUser", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
})

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3001, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

I get an empty object, even though I am trying to send

```
{
    a:1
}
```

I have

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

included in my server file and also tried changing the fetch `mode` to be `cors` instead of `no-cors`

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "progression-tracker-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "env": "0.0.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: What version of express or are you requiring body parser directly? Where is the complete code?

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ I updated my answer with the full code and module versions

Comment: in post, use res.send(req.params)

Comment: @Dileephell I get a Response that has a `status` of 0 and `body:null`

Comment: In express3+ body parser is built in. Change it to express and test. Dont understand either why you're using dotenv and env.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ dotenv and env was a mistake.  Didn't know I had both of them installed.  I tested using the express body parser (I did `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));` and `app.use(express.json());`) and still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `no-cors` option.  If you remove that, then it works for me when I reproduce the code you show.

The reason for that is that `no-cors` only allows a limited set of headers and does not allow a content-type of `application/json` like you are trying to use.  So, presumably that content-type is stripped by the browser and thus your bodyparser middleware does not match and doesn't do its job so the body of the post is never read and `req.body` ends up empty.

So, to make that type of request, you need to remove the `no-cors` option and if it is a cross origin request, then you need to enable that specific type of CORs request in your server or change your struture so that request isn't cross
origin.

Comment: When I remove it, I get a  blocked by CORS policy

Comment: @StuartFong -  Well, then your server needs to enable CORs for that type of request.  You can only do "simple" requests with  `no-cors` and `application/json` content-type is NOT a simple request.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode for more info on `no-cors`.

Comment: @StuartFong - FYI, body-parser is built into Express so you can use `app.use(express.json())` and don't need to load the separate body-parser module.